# How to correctly implement a props callback function in the useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, eslint

I want to use `useEffect()` to detect changes to a state value and pass that value to a parent component using a callback function received as a prop. I can't figure out a way to do this without disabling the eslint missing dependency warning. I have this problem on both the child component and that child's child.

Here is the parent implementation:

```
const updateValues = (newValues) => {
  setValues({ ...values, ...newValues });
};

<GeneralUpdates onUpdate={updateValues} />
```

Here is the first child (GeneralUpdates):

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    description: '',
  });

// This handles form input changes
const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
  setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
};

useEffect(() => {
  onUpdate(values);
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [values]);

<FilesUpload handleChange={onUpdate}/>
```

And this is the child's child (FilesUpload):

```
const [featuredPhotos, setFeaturedPhotos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  handleChange({ featuredPhotos });
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [featuredPhotos]);
```

Adding `handleChange` as a dependency results in an infinite re-rendering loop. I've tried every solution I can find but must be missing something here.

Comment: you can disable or you will have to memoize `handleChange` because that function value probably keeps changing on every re-render which triggers `useEffect` again.

Comment: from where is this `setValues` in first child is coming from? If you can add a small example on code sandbox or code pen that would help others a lot

Comment: I've added it @RaheelRiaz, also added the solution that worked for me as an answer but definitely interested in more insight.

Answer (score 4):

A colleague helped me find a solution to this—passing a named function to useEffect rather than the anonymous one:

```
const updateCallback = () => {
    onUpdate(values);
  };

useEffect(updateCallback, [values]);
```

Comment: damm this should be part of the react documentation for useEffect, its such a common pattern.

Comment: One thing to note that this is basically disabling the eslint checking of the dependency list. For example it won't complain if you remove the values param from the deps.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any problem with disabling eslint for this particular rule if you know 100% what you are doing.

However you can still get around this without disabling eslint by using `useCallback hook` for `handleChange` function being passed from parent if parent is a functional component

```
// in parent
const handleChange = useCallback(({featuredPhotos}) => {
    // Do what you want to do here
}, []);
```

If parent is not a functional component, make sure you aren't using arrow function in render while passing it as props and you should be ok

```
handleChange = ({featuredPhotos}) => {
   ...
}

render() {
   return (
       <Child handleChange={this.handleChange} />
   )
}
```

EDIT:

for your case, you can update the implementation by using useCallback for updateValue function and inside it use functional setState

```
const updateValues = useCallback((newValues) => {
  setValues(prevValues => ({ ...prevValues, ...newValues }));
}, []);
```

Comment: Should note that this can only work if the parent component is also a functional component.

Comment: This is helpful but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case as there is a component in between the two being discussed. The structure is more like: functional parent component with `handleChange` callback -> functional component handling form input with `useEffect` -> functional component handling featuredPhotos. Also when I implement the `useCallback` hook as described I receive the same missing deps error on it.

Comment: Please share the implementation of handleChange in parent and also how you pass it on to the child as props

Comment: I updated my answer, while you answer will work if useEffect just needs to call onUpdate but if it has more logic, it will cause you troubles.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding one more solution which keeps also eslint happy:

```
const callback = useRef();
callback.current = onUpdate;     

useEffect(() => {
  callback.current(values);
}, [values, callback]);
```